# Referencing from Annex

Tags: overleaf

I am using a template for my thesis and I trying to reference something I have written it in the annex like this using \label in annex and \ref where I reference it.

The problem is I cannot reference something from the annex. I cannot find its label. Probably because annex is not a chapter or something. Is there any suggestion on how to do this?

The structure of my document:

```
    \documentclass[twoside]{esi-tfm}
\usepackage{custom}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\input{metadata.tex}


\begin{document}

\cover
\bastardtitle
\frontpage
\signatures

\frontmatter
\copyrightpage
\jury
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\lstlistoflistings
\input{acro.tex}


\mainmatter

\input{intro.tex}
\input{webography.tex}
\appendix
\appendixtitle


In this annex are given some extended examples of code that will help understand the work better. \label{I WANT TO REFRENCE THIS SENTENCE FROM ANNEX}

\backmatter
\bibliography{main}
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

When I put \label in appendix/annex, I get a reference in the last section of my document which is webography.com

Thanks

Comment: if the annex is in the same document, referencing should work. please provide small but complete document, which will show your problem. referencing should be independent from used editor and used latex distribution (so it has not much with overleaf)

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: this is only fragment of code which we can't test. complete document meaning that it start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and not contain any files which we havent.. in which you should have one label (in annex or appendix)  and referencing in text..

Comment: Does it look better now? I think it fulfills the requireemnts you have put in your comment

Comment: no, we haven't your files `metadata`, `webography` etc. however, you can't label a some sentence but elements like `sections`, `captions` etc. consequently you got reference to the last `section`.

Comment: Ok, so now I see a problem. When I write  asection in this annex/appendix I see only .1 NameOfSection instead of 7.1 NameofSection for example.

Comment: Do you think that it should appear normally like an usuall section for example 7.1 or is it normal for a section inside annex to remain section .1??

Comment: It is impossible to say anything about your document as you have given no clues about the definitions you are using  nor given an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: The thing is that my template is large dont know what to post

Comment: does your annex have a number such as 1 or a or soemthing, , if sections are numbered as `\thechapter.arabic{section}` then teh assumption is that they are all in a numbered chapter or appendix, ir you need to redefine \thesection`

Comment: Your example does not need to be much bigger than what you have already, but should use files that people can use.  Start form a _copy_ of your document and delete everything you can delete which still showing the problem.

Comment: If it's fine for you to share the project, click on the "Share" button at the top of your Overleaf project, and then "Turn on link-sharing". Then post the **read-only link**.

Comment: My guess is that you are using `\appendixtitle` to set the heading "Appendix".  Instead, it's usual to use `\chapter{<appendix title>}`, which will give an anchor for cross-references.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I am posting the solution I found.

I put the code in my Annex in this way:

```
\begin{sltlisting} [caption= Caption, label=Label]

\end {lstlisting}
```

Then I referenced using `\ref{Label}` and it worked.

Comment: Which package provides environment sltlisting?